# Create class with multiple indexed properties

Tags: excel, vba, class

I'm trying to create a class with multiple properties that are indexed by the same number I pass into the property. I've tried several configurations of code, my latest failure being this:

```
'dataTypeClass class module
Private ap() As String
Private dt() As String

Public Property Get apos(index As Long) As Variant
Set apos = ap(index)
End Property

Public Property Get dataType(index As Long) As Variant
Set dataType = dt(index)
End Property

Public Property Let apos(index As Long, apVal As String)
ap(index) = apVal
End Property

Public Property Let dataType(index As Long, dtVal As String)
dt(index) = dtVal
End Property
```

I get this error code mostly:

[image]

Expecting to use below to get "INT" and "" for item 1 in sub below.

```
Sub classTest()

Dim d As New dataTypeClass
d(1).dataType = "INT"
d(1).apos = ""
Debug.Print d(1).dataType & d(1).apos
End Sub
```

What several things am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Taking suggestions below (such as editing my question rather than commenting), I'm setting the variants to strings, and using `let` instead of `set`. Since I did indeed get a subscript out of range, I need to initialize the class, but do I need to `redim index`? How might I do that if the index will have a different maximum each time I run the script?

Comment: BigBen raises a good point: your arrays aren't initialized, so assigning to an index will throw error 9 / index out of bounds - unless you've simply omitted the `Class_Initialize` handler that initializes them.

Comment: Also pointed out in a comment below, but `d(1).dataType` and `d(1).apos` should be `d.dataType(1)` and `d.apos(1)`.

Comment: RE: Your last edit - that is entirely up to your implementation. Nobody here knows how you intend to use this class, nor what it's for. But if you don't know how many items you're going to need, consider encapsulating a `Collection` instead of an array.

Comment: @JohnyL that's true, but wildly irrelevant to this question, and further confusing the OP.

Comment: @JohnyL try `public string Foo { get { return _foo; } int set { _foo = value; } }` in C#, tell me how that goes.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Syntax error

Comment: @JohnyL IKR! Method overloading doesn't like conflicting types either! You can't have `int Foo() { return 42; }` and `string Foo() { return "42"; }` and call that method overloading.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I didn't understand what you tried to say, but I just realized that my note about overloading has nothing to do with the question. ))

Answer (score 5):

The `apos` property<sup>1</sup> gets a `Variant` at the specified `index`; the implementation suggests that the encapsulated `ap(index)` is an `Object`, so the return type should probably be `Object` instead of `Variant`:

```
Public Property Get apos(index As Long) As Variant
Set apos = ap(index)
End Property
```

The setter uses `Let` assignment, which is hackish, but allowed given the value is `Variant` - oh wait no, it's a `String`!

```
Public Property Let apos(index As Long, apVal As String)
ap(index) = apVal
End Property
```

You're getting this error because, as the error states, the property definition is inconsistent. If `ap(index)` is a `String`, then the getter should look like this:

```
Public Property Get apos(index As Long) As String
apos = ap(index)
End Property
```

If `ap(index)` is an `Object`, then the *setter* should look like this:

```
Public Property Set apos(index As Long, apVal As Object)
Set ap(index) = apVal
End Property
```

...and the getter like this:

```
Public Property Get apos(index As Long) As Object
Set apos = ap(index)
End Property
```

Or like this:

```
Public Property Get apos(index As Long) As Variant
Set apos = ap(index)
End Property

Public Property Set apos(index As Long, apVal As Variant)
Set ap(index) = apVal
End Property
```

In other words:

- The RHS/value parameter of `Property Let`/`Property Set` needs to be the same type as the return type of the same-name `Property Get` member.
- If the type is an object type, use `Property Set` for assignments.
- If the type is a value type, use `Property Let` for assignments.
- Avoid `Variant` if possible.
- Do not use `Set` to assign anything other than an object reference.

---

<sup>1</sup>All of this is also true for the `dataType` property.

Comment: When I seen the title of this Question, I thought to myself:  "oh look, he's playing Matt's song".  Nice hat.

Answer (score 4):

You have a variant for the return type of your Get but your Let additional param is using a string. Perhaps you need  `dtVal As Variant`? As mentioned in comments and other answer there are additional things to consider; some will be implementation specific.

[Quote:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/definitions-of-property-procedures-for-the-same-property-are-inconsistent)

> The parameters for Property Get, Property Let, and Property
>   Setprocedures for the sameproperty must match exactly, except that the
>   Property Let has one extra parameter, whose type must match the return
>   type of the corresponding Property Get, and the Property Set has one
>   more parameter than the corresponding Property Get, whose type is
>   either Variant, Object, a class name, or an object library type
>   specified in an object library. This error has the following causes
>   and solutions:
>
> The number of parameters for the Property Get procedure isn't one less
>   than the number of parameters for the matching Property Let or
>   Property Set procedure. Add a parameter to Property Let or Property
>   Set or remove a parameter from Property Get, as appropriate.
>
> The parameter types of Property Get must exactly match the
>   corresponding parameters of Property Let or Property Set, except for
>   the extra Property Set parameter. Modify the parameter declarations in
>   the corresponding procedure definitions so they are appropriately
>   matched.
>
> The parameter type of the extra parameter of the Property Let must
>   match the return type of the corresponding Property Get procedure.
>   Modify either the extra parameter declaration in the Property Let or
>   the return type of the corresponding Property Get so they are
>   appropriately matched.
>
> The parameter type of the extra parameter of the Property Set can
>   differ from the return type of the corresponding Property Get, but it
>   must be either a Variant, Object, class name, or a validobject library
>   type.
>
> Make sure the extra parameter of the Property Set procedure is either
>   a Variant, Object, class name, or object library type.
>
> You defined a Property procedure with an Optional or a ParamArray
>   parameter. ParamArray and Optional parameters aren't permitted in
>   Property procedures. Redefine the procedures without using
>   thesekeywords.

Comment: Also needs to get rid of `Set` in `Set apos = ap(index)` and `Set dataType = dt(index)`.

Comment: It's `Private ap() As String` and `Private dt() As String`, (not `As Variant`), so I'd assume the return type of `Property Get` should be `As String` right?

Comment: Also going to need help on those unallocated arrays and the `classTest`. `d(1).dataType` should presumably be `d.dataType(1) = "INT"`, but will throw a subscript out of range...

Comment: Yeah... thank you. I noticed a few things including the issue around use of set as is. But we thankfully we also have Matt and you on the case!

Comment: Me too. Lol. :-)